# Video encoding and keyframes

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, x264, keyframe

I am transcoding a video frame by frame and using x264+ffmpeg to encode. The original video plays fine, but the first few frames of my transcoded vide show grey artefacts. I understand this is because of time compression and these artefacts disappear after a few frames.

See these two pictures which are the first and second frames. The third frame is normal (i.e. no grey artefact and not blurry like the second one)
[image: First frame]
[image: Second frame]

How can I force the first frame to be a key frame (ie fully encoded in my output video) so that these artefacts do not show?

**Edit - more details**

Here is what I am doing more in details. I used bit form differents tutorials to read a video frame by frame and reencode each frame to a new video. My encoding parameters are the following:

```
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(c, *codec);
c->codec_id = codec_id;
c->bit_rate = output_bitrate;
/* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
c->width    = output_width;
c->height   = output_height;
/* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
 * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
 * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
 * identical to 1. */
st->r_frame_rate.num = output_framerate_num;
st->r_frame_rate.den = output_framerate_den;
c->time_base.den = output_timebase_den;
c->time_base.num = output_timebase_num;
c->gop_size      = 3; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
c->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) {
    /* just for testing, we also add B frames */
    c->max_b_frames = 2;
}
if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
    /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
     * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
     * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
    c->mb_decision = 2;
}
c->max_b_frames = 2;
c->scenechange_threshold = 0;
c->rc_buffer_size = 0;
c->me_method = ME_ZERO;
```

Then I process each frame, probably doing something wrong there. The decoding bit:

```
while(av_read_frame(gFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) {
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==gVideoStreamIndex) {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(gVideoCodecCtx, pCurrentFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(frameFinished) {
            [...]
            if(firstPts == -999) /*Initial value*/
                firstPts = packet.pts;
            deltaPts = packet.pts - firstPts;
            double seconds = deltaPts*av_q2d(gFormatCtx->streams[gVideoStreamIndex]->time_base);
            [...]
            muxing_writeVideoFrame(pCurrentFrame, packet.pts);
        }
    }
}
```

The actual writing:

```
int muxing_writeVideoFrame(AVFrame *frame, int64_t pts)
{
frameCount = frameCount +1;
if(frameCount > 0)
{
    if (video_st)
        video_pts = (double)video_st->pts.val * video_st->time_base.num /
                    video_st->time_base.den;
    else
        video_pts = 0.0;

    if (video_st && !(video_st && audio_st && audio_pts < video_pts))
    {
        frame->pts = pts;//av_rescale_q(frame_count, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base);
        write_video_frame(oc, video_st, frame);
    }
}

return 0;
}

static int write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st, AVFrame *frame)
{
    int ret;
    static struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
    //LOGI(10, frame_count);
    AVCodecContext *c = st->codec;

    /* encode the image */
    AVPacket pkt;
    int got_output;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
    pkt.size = 0;
ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
    exit(1);
}
/* If size is zero, it means the image was buffered. */
if (got_output) {
    if (c->coded_frame->key_frame)
        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    pkt.stream_index = st->index;
    /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
} else {
    ret = 0;
}

    if (ret != 0) {
        LOGI(10, av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }
    frame_count++;
    return got_output;
}
```

Comment: Unless you show the ffmpeg command and the complete console output then we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your video does not start with a
[**keyframe**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types). To fix this I use [**AviDemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux). Starting with version 2.6

- MP4 Muxer
- MP4v2 Muxer

and possibly more support video starting without a keyframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely in decoding part not in encoding (x264 can't produce such artifacts). And as was said above it looks like you start decoding not from keyframe (or may be your stream is open-gop and you didn't discard first B-frames).

Comment: To confirm this I have tried discarding the first 10 frames I decode - which is way more than the number of corrupt frames I get on my transcoded video. This gives exactly the same result. I also tried to display all the decoded frames on the screen and they look good. It must be something wrong on the encoding side of things.

Comment: Upload small encoded sample somewhere. But I still think it is decoding problem or you use x264 API incorrectly (send it frames broken somewhere in the middle of your transcoding chain).

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have posted an [example original file](http://dl.free.fr/jazSYmaGF) (select "Valider et telecharger le fichier" in the red box) and the resulting [transcoded file](http://dl.free.fr/vf0MF8LZ5) that shows the artifacts.

Comment: Looks like around 4 first frames get insanely high QP-values (very low bitrate) and so effectively decimated to solid gray blocks. So I would guess something wrong in they way how you use libx264 in ffmpeg. As your sample is VFR it is most probably incorrect values of PTS are send so it screw libx264's ratecontrol (incorrect frames durations so wrong bitrates). Btw "--keyint 3" is insanely short GOP for any use case.

Comment: I encoded your sample with x264 and same params as you effectively used "x264 vid.3gp -o test.mp4 --threads=1 --bframes=2 --keyint 3 --no-scenecut --bitrate=1001" and it looks OK (and that is what you should get if use libx264 correctly): [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/d7jrdf).

Comment: Also I would recommend to read what ffmpeg/libx264 writes into log (av_log_set_callback). I am sure there are a lot of warnings there. Because it looks like you force frames types somehow (only first frame is I-frame and others are P-frames) and so violates GOP size (--keyint 3) you set and there should be warning about that.

Comment: Thanks very much for these explanations. I have added code samples in the original post. I agree that my settings seem wrong as I mainly use data form the decoded frame to encode new ones.